# How can I prevent my PWA reloading on a Share Request

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, web-share-target

How can I prevent my PWA from restarting when it receives the POST request which comes from a user doing a Share in another app and selecting my PWA as the "share_target".

I have everything working in the service worker to process the 'fetch' event and the shared content, but can't prevent it from restarting.

My code aligns with this Bard answer https://g.co/bard/share/9e1f87e4b8a8

Any help much appreciated.